# Como usar um CheckButton do Tkinter para interagir com um dataframe Pandas

Tags: pandas, tkinter

Estou tentando fazer uma interação com um dataframe em Pandas, já tentei várias opções de solução que encontrei aqui no stackoverflow, mas ainda não obtive êxito. Se alguém puder me ajudar, eu ficaria muito grato.

Objetivo:

> Para cada linha do dataframe gerar um Checkbutton;
> Escolher duas "cidades" do dataframe;
> "printar" na tela o "id" da cidade;
> Ao atingir o limite de 2 cidades, "printar" na tela que o limite de escolha foi atingido.

Problema:

> Não estou conseguindo enviar o "id_cidade" para a função "on_click()"

Saída:
[0]
[0, 0]
Limite de escolha atingido

Segue abaixo o código em que estou batendo cabeça:

```
# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-
from tkinter import *
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

class Cidades:
    def __init__(self, root):
        dataframe = pd.DataFrame({"id": [1,2,3,4,5], "city":["Curitiba", "Belem", "Fortaleza", "Cuiaba", "Niteroi"]})
        self.frame = Frame(root).grid(row=0, column=0)
        
        self.total_cidades = []
        self.lista_cidades(dataframe)
   
        
    def lista_cidades(self, dataframe):
        Label(self.frame, text="ESCOLHA DUAS CIDADES").grid(row=0, column=0)
        i=0
        while i < len(dataframe["id"]):
            for row in dataframe["id"].T.iteritems():
                self.cidade = IntVar()
                id_cidade = dataframe["id"][i]
                btn_escolhe_cidade = Checkbutton(self.frame, variable=self.cidade, onvalue=id_cidade, offvalue=0, command = self.on_click)
                btn_escolhe_cidade.grid(row=i+2, column=0)
                Label(self.frame, text=dataframe["city"][i]).grid(row=i+2, column=1)
                i+=1
    
    
    
    def on_click(self):
        id_cidade = self.cidade.get()
        self.total_cidades.append(id_cidade)
        
        if len(self.total_cidades) <= 2:
            print(self.total_cidades)
        else:
            print("Limite de escolha atingido")

root = Tk()
Cidades(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Consegui solucionar o problema, usei a funcao "partial".

```
from functools import partial

(...)
btn_escolhe_cidade = Checkbutton(self.frame, variable=self.cidade, onvalue=id_cidade, offvalue=0, command = partial(self.on_click, id_cidade))
```